# How to filter many Slicers with different names, but the same source?

Tags: excel, vba, slicers

I have a macro that moves the data values into 2 Data Tabs.

The 2 data tabs that are all Dynamically Named Ranges "COMBINED" AND "STORE".

They are used in 9 different Pivot Tables (9 different worksheets); which also have Named Slicers.
("COMBINED" is connected to 8 Slicers. "STORE" is connected to 1 Slicer.)

After running the macro, All time frames are selected in the Slicers.
[image: Before]

I would like to filter the slicers to one "Time" period after I run the macro, and refresh the Pivot tables.
[image: After]

Here are my Slicer Names and settings:

[image: Name Manager] [image: Slicer Settings]

As a starting point, I ran a recorded Macro, and got this (Condensed version):

```
Sub RecordedMacro()

    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_TIME1")
        .SlicerItems("Kroger YTD - Ending 2021  PD 04  WK 4  (16)").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("Latest 13 Wks - Ending 2021  PD 04  WK 4  (16)").Selected = _
        False
        .SlicerItems("Latest 26 Wks - Ending 2021  PD 04  WK 4  (16)").Selected = _
        False
        .SlicerItems("Latest 4 Wks - Ending 2021  PD 04  WK 4  (16)").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("Latest 52 Wks - Ending 2021  PD 04  WK 4  (16)").Selected = _
        False
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_TIME2")
        .SlicerItems("Kroger YTD - Ending 2021  PD 04  WK 4  (16)").Selected = True
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_TIME3")
        .SlicerItems("Kroger YTD - Ending 2021  PD 04  WK 4  (16)").Selected = True
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_TIME4")
        .SlicerItems("Kroger YTD - Ending 2021  PD 04  WK 4  (16)").Selected = True
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_TIME5")
        .SlicerItems("Kroger YTD - Ending 2021  PD 04  WK 4  (16)").Selected = True
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_TIME6")
        .SlicerItems("Kroger YTD - Ending 2021  PD 04  WK 4  (16)").Selected = True
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_TIME7")
        .SlicerItems("Kroger YTD - Ending 2021  PD 04  WK 4  (16)").Selected = True
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_TIME8")
        .SlicerItems("Kroger YTD - Ending 2021  PD 04  WK 4  (16)").Selected = True
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_TIME")
        .SlicerItems("Kroger YTD - Ending 2021  PD 04  WK 4  (16)").Selected = True
    End With
    
End Sub
```

**Is there a way to condense this since the slicers are from the same source?  Maybe an Array?**

I have seen posts/questions about OLAP Tables, but this is not an OLAP table.
Also, how to select multiple selections within one Pivot Table.

[How to select one slicer = true and remaining = false in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51507498/how-to-select-one-slicer-true-and-remaining-false-in-vba)

[VBA change Slicer item selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51193840/vba-change-slicer-item-selection)

Based on these sources, I created this code, but it only updates one Slicer at a time:

```
Sub FilterSlicer()

    Dim slr As Slicer
    Dim sc As SlicerCache
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim i As Long

    Set sc = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_TIME1")
        'Set sc = slr.SlicerCache

    For Each pt In sc.PivotTables
        pt.ManualUpdate = True 'Stops PivotTable from refreshing after each PivotItem is changed
    Next pt

    With sc

    'At least one item must remain visible in the Slicer at all times, so make the first
    'item visible, and at the end of the routine, check if it actually  *should* be visible
        .SlicerItems(1).Selected = True
        
    'Hide any other items that aren't already hidden.
    'Note that it is far quicker to check the status than to change it.
    ' So only hide each item if it isn't already hidden
    For i = 1 To .SlicerItems.Count
        If .SlicerItems(i).Selected Then .SlicerItems(i).Selected = False
    Next i
    
    End With
    
    For Each pt In sc.PivotTables
        pt.ManualUpdate = False
    Next pt
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you can change to Sub FilterSlicer(SlicerName) / Set sc = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(SlicerName), and then when you call the macro outside is possible to do For Each SL in  ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches , Call FilterSlicer(SL) Next SL

Comment: @RodrigoMoraes I'm not sure I understand.  Where would I put the individual slicer names? In the 'outside' macro?

Comment: Sub Test() Call FilterSlicer([SlicerNameHere]) ... if you do this it will pass the slicer name to your actual code and execute the routine. The next thing to do is make a “For Each” step to make this call to every slicer in workbook